# TI 84 CAN'T SOLVE THIS SIMPLE PROBLEM

Tags: recreational-mathematics

why does my TI 84 answer .06 divided by 365 = 1.643835616E -4?? the answer is .000164383

Comment: They're the same

Comment: it will solve .6 divided by 365

Comment: It's written in [scientific notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation). Specifically, $1.643835616 \times 10^{-4} = 0.0001643835616$.

Comment: it's not set up to answer in that type of notation so why is it reverting to a notation that is useless when doing financial computations in function form

Comment: i can add the extra zero because it's obvious what it's doing but on my upcoming exam this will be a pain

Comment: so does anyone know why?

Comment: i have a 5 dollar calculator that can do this

Comment: All caps is the equivalent of yelling. Don't yell.

Answer (score 4):

It's the same. When your calculator says `E`, that means "times ten raised to the power of".

So `1.643835616E -4` means
$$
1.643835616\cdot 10^{-4}=1.643835616\cdot0.0001
$$
which is exactly the answer you say you expected.